# Provide client secret to vsts release during deployment

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xunit, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a asp.net core app and we are running xunit based E2E (end-to-end) tests  for testing. The test cases are obviously a separate project from the asp.net core app. During the deploy time in VSTS release pipeline, I want to read the client secret from the azure key-vault into the config.

Currently we have appsettings.json in xunit test project and we use IConfiguration framework to read those settings into config. Now I want to provide the client secret stored in key-vault to the above config. I can download the secret into a variable using the key-vault task in VSTS pipeline but how to use it to inject it into appsettings/config.

This is how my appsettings look:

`AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "SomeClientID",
    "ClientSecret": ""
  }`

ClientSecret is empty because on localhost it will pick from userSecrets on the local machine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows

Now how do I provide the ClientSecret while running the task in vsts pipeline.

Comment: You can set it by environment variable : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider

Answer (score 0):

- In your VSTS build add a variable AzureAd:ClientSecret

[image: variable]

Check if your code adds [environment variable configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider). (enabled by default)

Comment: I'm talking about the release time. We are using vsTest to run test cases and it won't pic up the environment variables.

Comment: How do you launch your tests ? Using `dotnet test` ?

Comment: Ok I get it, You need either to set your variable in the **appsettings.json** or in the **web.config** before publishing your artifacts. There isn't built-in token replacement task in VSTS but you can use this : https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme for sample

Comment: Or consider to use [Octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/) instead of VSTS to manage your release. With Octopus you can define variables per environment.

Comment: @aguafrommars Maybe no specifically in this case, but if you consider an environment a stage, ADO will allow [stage specific variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch)